# SQL - Trying to iterate through partitions to find duplicates

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, duplicates

So here's a bit of sample information:

```
ROW  |     PHONE     |   ID   |  NAME
_________________________________________
1      000-000-0000      3     Company1
2      000-000-0000     38     Company2
1      123-456-7890      0     Company3
2      123-456-7890      0     Company4
3      123-456-7890      0     Company5
1      197-865-4329      0     Company6
2      197-865-4329     18     Company7
1      654-987-1230     74     Company8
2      654-987-1230      2     Company9
1      951-753-8462      2     Company10
2      951-753-8462      3     Company11
3      951-753-8462      3     Company12
4      951-753-8462      3     Company13
```

This information was pulled from a table using the following code:

```
USE MyTable
GO

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AI.telephone1 ORDER BY AI.telephone1) AS Row
        ,AI.telephone1 AS [Main Phone #]
        ,AI.new_id AS [ID]
        ,AI.name AS [Account Name]
        ,AI.emailaddress1 AS [Email Address]
        ,AI.contactname AS [Primary Contact]
FROM AccountsInfo AI
WHERE AI.telephone1 IN (
        SELECT telephone1
        FROM MyDatabase.dbo.AccountsInfo AI
        WHERE telephone1 != 'NULL'
            AND telephone1 != '--'
        GROUP BY telephone1
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        )
ORDER BY telephone1
```

What I need to do now, but can't wrap my head around, is iterate through each partition and pull out only results with matching ID numbers. See below for what I want the table to look like in the end...

```
    PHONE    |   ID   |   NAME
_________________________________________
123-456-7890      0      Company3
123-456-7890      0      Company4
123-456-7890      0      Company5
951-753-8462      3      Company11
951-753-8462      3      Company12
951-753-8462      3      Company13
```

As you can see, Company 3, 4, and 5 made it to the results because they all three have matching ID numbers and matching phone numbers.  Company 11, 12, and 13 made it out their partition because they have matching ID numbers.  Company 10 was not pulled because it had a different ID number than 11, 12, and 13.

What I need done is for code to iterate through each partition (partitioned off by phone number) and check the ID number per row in partition against other rows in the partition.  The end result is going to be ONLY rows that have their ID number duplicated somewhere else within their partition.

If you need any other information, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT   AI.telephone1 AS [Main Phone #]
        ,AI.new_id AS [ID]
        ,AI.name AS [Account Name]
        ,AI.emailaddress1 AS [Email Address]
        ,AI.contactname AS [Primary Contact]
FROM AccountsInfo AI
INNER JOIN 
(
        SELECT telephone1,new_id
        FROM MyDatabase.dbo.AccountsInfo AI
        WHERE telephone1 != 'NULL'
            AND telephone1 != '--'
        GROUP BY telephone1, new_id
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) T
ON AI.telephone1 = T.telephone1
AND AI.new_id = T.new_id
ORDER BY AI.telephone1
```

Comment: This looks like it did it!  Thanks a ton!

We got over 20,000 results (which is good), so I'll report back if I tweak it at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `having`:

```
select
    "phone", "id"
from
    "data"
group by "phone", "id"
having ( min ( "row" ) < max( "row" ));
```

For more information and possibilities, have a look at [Joe Celko's Thinking in Sets](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/sql/9780080557526)

See [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3ebe9/1/0)